# Jquery: How to find nested ul with if statement

Tags: jquery, if-statement, navigation, nested

i'm trying to build a navigation. I want to find out if the < li > has a < ul >.
If < li > has a < ul > then the < ul > should fadeIn else it should open the link. I was already looking on the web.. couldn't find the perfect solution for my problem.

Here is my markup:

```
    <nav id="mobile-nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" title="Nav">Link</a>
                <ul class="second">
                    <li><a href="#" title="Sub Nav">Link 2</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#" title="Sub Nav 2">Link 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" title="Sub Nav 2">Link 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Sub Nav">Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Sub Nav">Link 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Nav">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Nav">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Nav">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

jquery:

```
$('#mobile-nav').on('click', 'a', function(){

if($(this).parent().has('ul')){
    alert("has ul");
    return false;
} else {
    alert("no ul");
    return false;
}
```

});

I tested it and it always gave me "has ul".

I also tried this:

```
if($(this).closest('li').has('ul')){
alert("has ul");
return false;
} else {
alert("no ul");
return false;
}
```

thanks for the help

Comment: where is the link that need to be opened

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cwmT7/ or http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cwmT7/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to test on a bool then you need to use `length`

**Example**

```
if($(this).parent().has('ul').length){
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be:

```
$(this).parent().find('ul').length
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NWwsu/)**